# Displaying Checkboxes Horizontally

Tags: android

Is it possible to display checkboxes horizontally (instead of vertically), similarly as options are displayed on Radio Buttons? In the affirmative, how can this be done?

Comment: If you have that checkbox's inside a LinearLayout you can set the layout to horizontal with android:orientation="horizontal" in the linear layout propertys, all elements inside the linearlayout will show horizontally

Comment: Thank you for your note.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrap them in a Linear Layout, give each one a `layout_weight`, then add as many as you'd like in a row.. although at some point in time they'd start to "squish" together and you should not do that..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        //Copy Paste More CheckBoxes...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your example.